# Tratar dados recebidos por AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

Boa tarde, eu estou enviar um valor via AJAX/Jquery que me acciona a funçao index do controlador notificações.
Ao receber um dado valor, eu quero que a funçao me direccione para outra página. Acontece que, ao receber esse dado valor, a função nao me redirecciona para outra página mas imprime-me essa página na consola.
Como é que faço para que me redireccione para a página?

O código que estou a utilizar é o seguinte:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#notifications').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
            url: '<?=base_url("notificacoes")?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              key: 'olá'
            },
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
            }
          });
        });   
      });
```

Controller :

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Notificacoes extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        return $this->load->view('norm');
    }
}
```

Botão :

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary pr-2" type="button" id="notifications" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="badge">0</span>
                    </button>
```

Comment: O `data` retorna o endereço de uma página? Se for, basta usar `location.href=data`

Answer (score 0):

O AJAX tem a principal finalidade de realizar requisições sem a necessidade de recarregar a página, ou seja, os valores retornados do servidor após a requisição serão manipulados pelo cliente sem a necessidade destes serem renderizados pelo servidor.

Para resolver o seu problema, não é necessário utilizar o ajax neste requisição, pois você solicitará ao servidor uma página diretamente ao invés de fazer a requisição, receber a resposta para então, fazer o redirecionamento.

Você pode fazer utilizando o JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#notifications').click(function() {
    window.location.href = '<?= base_url("notificacoes") ?>'
  });
});
```

Ou usando o próprio atributo HTML `onclick`:

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary pr-2" type="button" id="notifications" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="javascript:location.href='<?= base_url("notificacoes") ?>'">
    <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <span class="badge">0</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma caso queira validar o que esta vindo do ajax vc pode colocar o que veio do ajax em uma variavel como no exemplo retorno e fazer um if conferindo se é o que você quer, se for direciona para a url desejada:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#notifications').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
            url: '<?=base_url("notificacoes")?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              key: 'olá'
            },
            success: function(data) {
              var retorno = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (retorno == 'ok') {
                        window.location.href = "http://...";
                    } 
            }
          });
        });   
      });
```

mas caso a sua data do ajax já seja a url que você quer, pode ser feito da seguinte forma, porém o data já deve esta formatado para url:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#notifications').click(function(){
          $.ajax({
            url: '<?=base_url("notificacoes")?>',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              key: 'olá'
            },
            success: function(data) {
              window.location.href = data;
              //caso precise concatenar pode fazer assim
              window.location.href = "http://..."+data;
            }
          });
        });   
      });
```